# How to correct the problem of Select2 shuffles options after selection?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using [**select2**](https://select2.github.io/) plugin.

On fiddle, it works fine.
But Here are screenshots to explain my problem,

1. **This is default order of dropdown.**

[image: default order]

2. **When I select other option e.g. Inactive, then it goes to last option.**

[image: inactive selected]

3. **Check the position of inactive, after selected.**

[image: check inactive option position]

This is happening with every option.

I tried following alternatives,

- `$("select").select2();`
- `$(".select").select2();`
- `$("#select").select2();`

But nothing works,

*Have anyone faced this issue ?*

If Yes, please help me sort this problem.

Comment: You should add your code to the question.

Comment: This situation refers to those who might have faced this issue, because without it, can't solve. I am calling $("select").select2(); for select dropdown, what extra code you will need, thats it. This is the code.

Comment: I think it may be affected by something in your code.

Comment: I tried removing every single js libraries, but I am not sure, what exactly conflicting with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution,

```
$("select").on("select2:select", function(evt) {
        var element = evt.params.data.element;
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.detach();
        $(this).append($element);
        $(this).trigger("change");
});
```

This was the code which had used for some other purpose, but kept in common js file.

I shifted it where it specifically belongs.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I faced the same problem.